# Deploying netsuite website: no api version found error

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I am currently trying to deploy and upgrade to a netsuite website and I am getting an error on deployment that no API version was found:

`getFileNamedsearcherror Error: no API version found for 2015_1`

From my understanding Netsuite make API versions available up to 8 years ago, given it is 2023 it is close to being out of date but 2015_1 should still be available shouldn't it?

I attempted to update the version by altering the tool.js file to be as below but then I get a different error, it seems in 2015.2 netsuite made application ids a requirement and maybe that is not being injected properly?

```
getFileNamedsearcherror Error: Application ID mandatory but missing

// @module suitetalk  @class SuiteTalk
module.exports = {

    nsVersion: '2016_1',
    applicationId: "XXXXX"

    //@property searchPreferences
,   searchPreferences: {
        pageSize: '50'
    ,   returnSearchColumns: 'true'
    ,   bodyFieldsOnly: 'false'
    }

    // @method setCredentials
,   setCredentials: function (credentials)
    {
        this.credentials = credentials;

        if (credentials.nsVersion)
        {
            this.nsVersion = credentials.nsVersion
        }
        if (credentials.applicationId) {
            this.applicationId = credentials.applicationId
        }
    }

};
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: As of summer 2023: lowest available is 2016.2, lowest supported is 2020.2. See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3418621.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed:

> Important: Starting from NetSuite version 2019.1, endpoints that are
> 15 and more versions older will be retired.

which currently - July 2023 with NetSuite at 2023.1 - drops availability of anything before 2016.2.

Ref: [NetSuite Applications Suite : Support for Existing WSDL Versions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3418621.html)